# Magento Admin 404

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404, dedicated-hosting, dedicated-server

We recently migrated our Multi-domain magento setup from a shared host to a dedicated server.

All is working fine fronted, but when I try to go to the admin section I get a 404 error on anything after login.

It seems to work if I remove index.php from the url but then as soon as I click on another link in the admin section it 404's again with the index.php back in the URL.

Comment: I think that is a problem with the indexing and url rewrites. You will have to somehow manually reindex/ delete all old cache and rebuild everything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

-- You need to go your server directly and do this via SSH/ FTP

You have to delete the following file

```
app/etc/use_cache.ser
```

If you get an error after that  like

> Notice: Undefined index: 0 in
>   /srv/www/vhosts/javra.com/htdocs/munchad2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Config.php
>   on line 92

Then go to your Database Management.

- Open PhpMyAdmin
- Go to your database
- Click SQL
- Run the following SQL Query:

_

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Some thing strange happens with the cache when you move the databases from one server to another so it seems like you need to clear it out.

Comment: can't get to any... i get the log in form but then 404 when i log in

Comment: does it add the index.php after you log in?I think i had a similar problems once with this. and what version magento is it? and are you using custom skins?

Comment: Yeah... if i go to /admin I get the login screen as soon as i try to log in it adds the index.php to the URL.
using a custom skin that was working fine on previous install on old shared server. 
Version 1.5.0.1 of magento

Comment: there's no app/etc/use_cache.ser and I've also tried running the SQL query before with no luck.

Comment: Sorry pal - that is all I got .. You going to have to dig in log files somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help on this, finally found out the problem, turned out to be an issue with a rogue .htaccess file!

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate a bit and to add to the answer- for anybody in the future.. glad its sorted

Comment: Hi I had the same problem, and the reply with the "rogue .htaccess" file did not help at all.. What did help though, was this response: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/488069/. The frontname in my local.xml was set to "system" for some strange reason.

Answer (score 2):

Check in this way

```
> http://www.yourstore.com/index.php/admin/
```

or

```
>  http://www.yourstore.com/admin/
```

Comment: going to index.php/admin/ does nothing

and if i go to  /admin/ I can get the log in form but it then goes through to a 404 with index.php/admin/ in the url

Comment: All permissions are set to what they should be, still having problems

Answer (score 1):

After migration from www.domain1.com/magento/ to www.domain2.com/magento/ 
I was getting 500 Internal Server Error. 
So I just renamed my .htaccess to htaccess.txt.
And my frontend started working fine,
But at Backend  http://www.yourstore.com/admin/ I was getting Same 500 Internal Server error.

After trying many option suggested online nothing worked for me and after that I tried to access admin via following URL and voilà worked perfect, Hope this help others.

Try to access as this > http://www.yourstore.com/index.php/admin/

Answer (score 0):

Does the dedicated server have mod_rewerite enabled? Does the apache configuration allow .htaccess files to make changes to configuration directives via AllowOverride? Both of those are common ways that the Magento config gets pooched up.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I've also had an issue with ownership what was returning a 404 in admin. 
I'd been doing some work on securing the server and some files were owned as root, not apache. So a `chown -R apache:apache .` fixed it right up.