# localhost admin page is not coming in magento

Tags: magento, localhost, admin

I have installed backup of already running magento website including database and trying to up website on localsystem. I have installed all backup in innova named folder in my localsystem. Website is showing up on local system but formatting of website is not correct. when i type localhost/innova/admin it is taking me back to root directory.

I'm not able to open admin page to enter admin username and password. Please tell me how to get that admin page and how can i change the name from admin to any other name like xyz.

[Magento 404 on Admin Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724995/magento-404-on-admin-page)

I have used this link to rectify the problem but not able to get resolution. Please help..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have updated the rows in core_config_data :

```
web/unsecure/base_url

web/secure/base_url
```

to your localhost directory

Comment: Do you have flush all cache manually in the directory var/cache

Answer (score 0):

- login to phpmyadmin
- go to your magento database
- search for table `core_config_data`
- there would be two urls in value column
- replace both urls with your localhost magento urls like:
  `http://localhost/urlmagentodirectoryname/`
- and save it
- now check your site

Comment: r you using index.php before admin in your magento admin url like http://localhost/yourmagento/index.php/admin

Answer (score 0):

If your system is setup currently and your site is loaded correctly.Then try using index.php in your url.
For example:

> yourdomain/innova/index.php/admin

If you see the admin login page then login to admin panel.
Go to system->configuration.

Under Search Engine Optimization tab
set the Use Web Server Rewrites to "yes".Then you get rid of having index.php included.

Comment: I have tried using index.php but m not able to see login page it is just directing me to root directory....