# Magento admin page returning a 404

Tags: php, magento

I am using **magento** and I tried to restore a backup of my public site and the admin page is now returning a 404. I see that the Admin directory the admin code still exists but the admin page is not loading. I am quite at a loss. I was using the the following url for the site `www.mysite.com/admin`.

I am seeing posts related to custom url's and I don't believe this to be the case. I followed the info on this site

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724995/magento-404-on-admin-page

Here is the dump I'm seeing and I'm running Magento v1.9

> string(94) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(96) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(95) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(95) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(94) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(101) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(95) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(97) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(97) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Compiler/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(96) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(101) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(101) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(93) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(98) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/PageCache/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(91) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/controllers/IndexController.php" string(99) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/IndexController.php" string(96) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(103) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CurrencySymbol/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php" string(103) "/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CurrencySymbol/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php"

Any helps would be great.

Comment: HI andavis please try to run url like : www.mysite.com/index.php/admin once and check...

Comment: I'd guess that your restore hasn't restored ALL files - please check everything has been restored (or dump a copy of the correct Magento version over the top)