# How to get the admin login page in magento if it is showing 404 Error page not Found?

Tags: magento

I am doing a project in Magento.I have uploaded the project onto the server, the front end design of the project is showing correctly but when the admin login page is retrieved, its showing 404 error page not found.I have tried many solutions shown in the links below:

[Magento 404 on Admin Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724995/magento-404-on-admin-page)

But still it is not working.Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After moving from one server to another admin showing 404. Problem was in configuration. In `System->Configuration->Web->Secure->Use Secure URLs in Admin` was set to "Yes", but https wasn't configured.

I'm in table `core_config_data` found row with path *"web/secure/use_in_adminhtml"* and set "value" = 0.

The problem is not widespread, but you can check this. Hope this helps

Comment: have to change both ?

Comment: but the admin login page is coming when i am giving an index.php to the url...some path problem.Dnt know how to set this path..

Comment: anyone here to help me ?

Comment: Try to add .htaccess file to root directory

Comment: yes there must be no htacess file on live because sometime when we move sites hidden files don't get moved which causes this issues

Comment: Create file ".htaccess" in your magento directory and put content into the file from this https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/.htaccess